# React and Django - reloads on ajax/axios request

Tags: python, reactjs, axios, django-views

I have been stuck in a problem and I am trying to figure out what is causing issue, tried ChatGPT also but didn't solved the problem. The thing is that I am working on app which records my voice and then it send that audio/blob to the server. The flow of program is mentioned below:

- Mic is clicked the recording is start and state is changed
- Mic is again clicked for second time, the recording stops and state changed which cause save button on the top of the screen
- clicking on that button send post axios request to the server containing the blob data, but before I get the response my app reloads which cause the requests premature disconnects and cause the broken pipe error on server side.

Note: I am not changing the state when sending request I don't know what is causing this issue, can you help me out, I've been stuck for days in the problem.

Below I am going  to share both my server and component code:

- React component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './personalAssistent.css';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from 'axios';
import sendCookies from './sendcookie';

export default function PersonalAssistent() {
  const csrf = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
  const [isMicOn, setIsMicOn] = useState(false);
  const [save, setSave] = useState(false);

  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [bot, setBot] = useState('');


  console.log("App start");

  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const chunksRef = useRef([]);

  const startRecording = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener("dataavailable", handleDataAvailable);
        mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error accessing microphone:", error);
      });
    setIsMicOn(!isMicOn)
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorderRef.current && mediaRecorderRef.current.state !== "inactive") {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    }
    console.log('chucks: ',chunksRef.current);
    if (chunksRef.current.length > 0) {
        console.log('chunks is more then 0');
        setSave(!save)
      }
    setIsMicOn(!isMicOn)
  };
  
  const handleDataAvailable = (event) => {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
      chunksRef.current.push(event.data);
    }
  };

  const sendAudioToServer = async () => {
    const blob = new Blob(chunksRef.current, { type: "audio/wav" });
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('audio_file', blob);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/user/", formData, {
        headers: {
          "X-CSRFToken": csrf,
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Audio sent to the server successfully:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error sending audio to the server:", error);
      });
  };

  const toggleMic = () => {
    if (isMicOn) {
      console.log('mic off');
      stopRecording();
    } else {
      console.log('mic on');
      startRecording();
    }
    // setIsMicOn(!isMicOn);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid chatbot-page d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
      {save ? <button onClick={sendAudioToServer}>Save</button> : ''}
      <div className="row p-4">
        <div className="col-7">
          <div className="start-record bg-light border radius d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <div className="circle-btn bg-white" onClick={toggleMic}>
              <div className={`icon-mic-on ${isMicOn ? '' : 'd-none'}`}>
                <i className="fa-solid fa-microphone-lines fa-7x"></i>
              </div>
              <div className={`icon-mic-off ${isMicOn ? 'd-none' : ''}`}>
                <i className="fa-solid fa-microphone-lines-slash fa-7x"></i>
              </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-5">
          <div className="chat-history radius border bg-light p-3">
            <div className="conversation">
              {user ? (
                <div className="user-1 d-flex justify-content-start">
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2x m-2"></i>
                  <div className="user-input radius text-start p-2 px-3">
                    <p>{user}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ) : null}
              {bot ? (
                <div className="user-2 d-flex justify-content-end my-3">
                  <div className="bot radius text-start p-2 px-3">
                    <p>{bot}</p>
                  </div>
                  <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-user fa-2x m-2"></i>
                </div>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- Django server

```
def audio(audio_file):
    try:
        file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'chatbot/public/static/audio/me.wav')
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as destination:
            for chunk in audio_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        return True
    
    except Exception as err:
        print('error: ', err)
        return False

def userPrompt():
    filename = 'chatbot/public/static/audio/me.wav'
    try:
        with open(filename, "rb") as audio_file:
            transcript = openai.Audio.transcribe("whisper-1", audio_file)
        return transcript['text']
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error during audio transcription:", e)
        return 'error'


prompt = ''
def sendPrompt(request):
    global prompt
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.get('audio_file'):
        try:
            audio_file = request.FILES['audio_file']
            flag = audio(audio_file)
            if flag == True:
                prompt = userPrompt()
                print('\n\nYou:', prompt)
                return JsonResponse({'user':'prompt'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'user':'None'})
            
        except Exception as e:
                print('Error in userPrompt:', str(e))
                return ''
```

I have noticed if I comment out this line

```
flag = audio(audio_file)
```

on server side in sendPrompt() view, which is my request path, then app and server runs smoothly. I don't know what I am doing wrong to save the file, it looks correct to me. can anyone help me out?